# Function with dates as params that can be NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, date-range, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to implement a function with dates as parameters in PostgreSQL 9.3.5.
It should cover all the below conditions and return the results accordingly.

```
select * from tablename
where sid is not null and dob >= '11-14-2014' order by dob;
-- Only Start Date

select * from tablename
where sid is not null and dob <= '11-21-2014' order by dob;
-- Only End Date

select * from tablename
where sid is not null and dob between '11-10-2014' and '11-21-2014' order by dob; 
-- Both Start and End Dates are Given

select * from tablename
where sid is not null and dob is null; 
-- Both Start and End Dates are Null
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4194e/1)

But my above SQL Fiddle is not working as expected.

I want to have a generic implementation so that if tomorrow I have some more `new Date Fields` into the criteria search, then I just can add them in a `where condition`, but not in every line of `IF` Statement.

[**Updated SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/137dd/1)

Comment: Why do you need a seperate function? All of your above queries seem to do what you want. A seperate function seems a little bit too much for what it looks like since queries handle it just fine and much more readable.

Comment: @DrColossos I need a Function because i am trying to fetch details basing on the parameters passed(criteria based), so i want to make them into a function so that i can use the function to return results as there are doing while using them as single line queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be ***much simpler still***:

You can simplify the expression from @Clodoaldo's currently accepted answer to:

```
SELECT *
FROM   sampletest
WHERE  eid IS NOT NULL
AND   (_sd IS NULL AND _ed IS NULL OR
       _sd IS NULL AND dob <= _ed  OR
       _ed IS NULL AND dob >= _sd  OR
       dob BETWEEN _sd AND _ed);
```

- Once you compare `dob >= _sd`, there is no need to check `_sd is not null` additionally.
  The expression can only evaluate to `TRUE` with non-null `_sd` anyway.

But none of this is necessary:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_dob_dates(_sd date, _ed date)
  RETURNS SETOF sampletest AS
$func$
SELECT *
FROM   sampletest
WHERE  eid IS NOT NULL
AND    dob BETWEEN COALESCE(_sd, -infinity) AND COALESCE(_ed, infinity)
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

- Do not quote the language name. It's an identifier.
- Postgres provides the [special values `-infinity` and `infinity`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#AEN5861) for `timestamp` and `date` types. All you need is to default to those values with `COALESCE`.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0a5de/4) (for pg 9.3).

Aside: I would advise to use standard ISO dates **`'2014-11-10'`** instead of <strike>`'11-10-2014'`</strike>, which is potentially ambiguous and breaks with a different locale setting. [The manual advises as much.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE)

Comment: For infinity and making me understand better on Time Complexity. :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the function as returning a `set of` sampletest and then [return different query restults](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN58217) based on the arguments passed.

```
CREATE FUNCTION
  test_dob_dates(_sd date, _ed date)
RETURNS
  SETOF sampletest
AS
  $BODY$
    BEGIN
      IF _sd IS NOT NULL AND _ed IS NOT NULL THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM sampletest WHERE dob BETWEEN _sd AND _ed;
      ELSIF _sd IS NULL AND _ed IS NULL THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM sampletest WHERE dob IS NULL;
      ELSEIF _ed IS NOT NULL THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM sampletest WHERE dob <= _ed;
      ELSE
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM sampletest WHERE dob >= _sd;
      END IF;
    END;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE
  'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

The `eid IS NOT NULL` clause seems redundant as you have already defined `eid` to be a PRIMARY KEY and that means that it can never be NULL.

Comment: Is the code above is optimal and performs in best time. I see there is multiple lines of code repetition. Please, correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d6c80/2)

```
create function test_dob_dates(_sd date, _ed date)
returns setof sampletest as $body$
    select *
    from sampletest
    where
        eid is not null
        and (
            (_sd is null and _ed is null)
            or (_sd is not null and _ed is null and dob >= _sd)
            or (_sd is null and _ed is not null and dob <= _ed)
            or dob between _sd and _ed
        );
$body$ language sql stable;
```

Comment: I found that #Erwin Brandstetter post have some understandings related to infinity(some special values) use. Hope it is helpfull